# Rate of convergence of Bisection and false position method

Tags: numerical-methods, bisection

Rate of convergence for both Bisection and false position method is linear(one) but when we solve nonlinear equation $f(x)=0$ with both methods we see that false position method is converges rapidly than Bisection method although both methods have same rate of convergence.what is the reason behind this fact?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, both method are linear with the error satisfying $\epsilon_{n+1} = C \epsilon_n$.

For the [Bisection method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method#Analysis), $C$ is roughly equal to $1/2$ while for the [Regula-Falsi method](http://compmath-journal.org/dnload/Robin-Kumar-and-Vipan-/CMJV06I06P0290.pdf) $C = \frac{1}{2}\frac{f^{\prime\prime}(\xi)}{f^{\prime}(\xi)}$ for a twice differentiable map $f$, where $\xi$ is the root to be found.

So when you say that the false position method converge faster than the bisection method, this is not true in general. It depends on the position of the two initial points and on the value of $\frac{f^{\prime\prime}(\xi)}{f^{\prime}(\xi)}$. In particular if $\vert f^\prime(\xi) \vert$ is small, the convergence of the false position method can be slow.

Comment: Could you explain how you got the result for regula falsi? Typically the iteration enters a convex monotone mode after some initial steps and stalls. That means that one of the interval ends, say $b$, stays fixed and the other follows the iteration $$a_{k+1}-ξ=\frac{(a_k-ξ)f(b)-(b-ξ)f(a_k)}{f(b)-f(a_k)}\approx(a_k-ξ)\frac{f(b)-f'(ξ)(b-ξ)}{f(b)-f'(ξ)(a_k-ξ)}\approx (a_k-ξ)\frac{f(b)-f'(ξ)(b-ξ)}{f(b)},$$ so that the convergence rate (for the $a_k$, not the interval length) noticeably depends on the random position of the last change of $b$.

Comment: Rate of convergence is inside the document linked in the answer.

Comment: Then you did not read the section (nice first sentence, there should be a "false position method" in there) completely. The rate is $C'=Cε_0$ or in my notation $C'=\frac{f′'(ξ)}{2f′(ξ)}(b-ξ)$, which is correct for $b$ sufficiently close to $ξ$.

Comment: @LutzLehmann is almost correct here. The rate should be $$\frac{f''(\xi)}{2f'(\xi)}(b-x)$$ where $x$ is the root converged to, $b$ is the point failing to converge to the root, and $\xi$ is some value between $b$ and $x$.